# Streaming Live audio using Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to convince a friend of mine to use CN1 as his dev platform for mobile apps. One of the challenges he has brought up is the ability to stream live audio from a radio station using a CN1 app.

I have had a look at the docs and I can see examples of loading media files that are already on the phone, but I cannot see an example of where you point it at a URL and stream live audio.

**As you have probably guessed he is interested in developing radio apps for remote radio stations that don't already have their own**

Is it possible to do this in CN1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error "Video Playing is not supported on this platform", you have to put true to `isVidio` parameter like this when handling video stream.

```
Media audio = MediaManager.createMedia(streamingUrl, true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

That's quite possible with CN1 and number of developers have done that in the past.

You can use `MediaManager` and point it to your remote streaming URL.

Below works for playing an audio file from remote URL and could work for streaming:

```
Form radio = new Form(new BorderLayout());
Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(() -> {
    try {
        Media audio = MediaManager.createMedia(streamingUrl, false);
        audio.prepare();
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
            final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(audio);
            player.setAutoplay(true);
            audio.setNativePlayerMode(false);
            radio.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, player);
            radio.revalidate();
        });
    } catch (IOException err) {
        Log.e(err);
        ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Error streaming audio: " + err);
    }
});
radio.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for this. When I run this code I am presented with a media player with the word 'video' in the centre. When I add my own custom url ( which points at a radio stream ) I get this error ..."Video Playing is not supported on this platform". I am not sure why I am seeing 'video' messages.

Comment: I used Fiddler to try and catch the url ... this is what I have ... http://radionz-ice.streamguys.com/concert.mp3.m3u

Comment: Ok that url would not work. I have managed to get the following url to work in VLC ...http://radionz-ice.streamguys.com/concert.mp3 ... but it still gives me the 'video' error in CNO

Comment: What I find interesting is that when I use the built in CNO Network Monitor I don't see any traffic ... it obviously fails before it makes the call

Comment: It gets stranger still. I stepped through the code and found that this line causes the 'video' error in the log output ... "final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(audio);"

Comment: This uses the native OS to play the media. The simulator will act very differently from the devices! The thing is that it won't act "better". One of the big problems in JavaFX is that it **amazingly** can't play media off https only http. So some streams might fail just because JavaFX sucks. We must use it for media internally as it's the only media API for Java developers